# How to reduce flickering of AlphaBlend enabled Form application in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

**How reduce flickering in Delphi ?**

It is very common and popular question not only in this forum but also all the Delphi forum, but I am not having not any concrete solution for this, so I am asking it again.

I am having very simple Delphi XE2 project without any code. When I run the application it always create flickering though `DoubledBuffered:=true` and `ParentDoubledBuffered:=true`.

Here is my code for `.pas File` :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants,
  System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Buttons;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    Label2: TLabel;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    BitBtn1: TBitBtn;
    BitBtn2: TBitBtn;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

and here is the code of my `.dfm File`:

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  AlphaBlend = True
  AlphaBlendValue = 230
  BorderIcons = [biSystemMenu, biMinimize]
  BorderStyle = bsSingle
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 300
  ClientWidth = 600
  Color = clWhite
  DoubleBuffered = True
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  GlassFrame.Enabled = True
  GlassFrame.SheetOfGlass = True
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poDesktopCenter
  Visible = True
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Label1: TLabel
    Left = 20
    Top = 74
    Width = 160
    Height = 13
    AutoSize = False
    Caption = 'Label1'
  end
  object Label2: TLabel
    Left = 20
    Top = 124
    Width = 160
    Height = 13
    AutoSize = False
    Caption = 'Label2'
  end
  object Edit1: TEdit
    Left = 200
    Top = 70
    Width = 360
    Height = 21
    Alignment = taCenter
    AutoSize = False
    TabOrder = 0
    Text = 'Edit1'
  end
  object Edit2: TEdit
    Left = 200
    Top = 120
    Width = 360
    Height = 21
    Alignment = taCenter
    AutoSize = False
    TabOrder = 1
    Text = 'Edit2'
  end
  object BitBtn1: TBitBtn
    Left = 200
    Top = 224
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'BitBtn1'
    ParentDoubleBuffered = True
    TabOrder = 2
  end
  object BitBtn2: TBitBtn
    Left = 485
    Top = 224
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'BitBtn2'
    ParentDoubleBuffered = True
    TabOrder = 3
  end
end
```

I have found so many application created in `Delphi` like [SetFileDate 2.0](http://no-nonsense-software.com/freeware/).

I have seen the `.exe File` in `PE Explorer` and I have found that the owner has defined `OnShow` event.
I have also observed another major difference that when I double click on the application the form is shown in my PC requires more time than my application i.e. there is some more delay than me before showing the form after double clicking on the application.

Another thing is that Firstly the `Edit` area becomes black at the first instant at the time of flickering sometimes the `Form Background` also. I have observed very minutely in several times before asking the question here. Please don't take otherwise, as I am a learner, not having so may fundas like others.

Previously, I was using `Timer` for `Form.Create Event`, now a days, I am not interested in `Timer`.

**Please give some Example Code.**

Comment: I want to mean that the `Form Creation` is not smooth. There is some shuddering at the time of `form Creation`. Please see minutely.

Comment: Are you running your application in the debugger or normally?

Comment: Ah, you have alpha blending turned on.

Comment: My application runs normally and I have also seen the flicker after compiling the application in both `Debug` and `Release` mode.

Comment: I need the `AlphaBlend` to be `True` because my requirement is `SemiTransparent Form`.

Comment: Then please emphasize this in your question. That's very important fact quite hidden in your form's code.

Comment: Here `BorderStyle` is `bsSingle`.

Comment: `VCL Fix Pack` is not for me it gives error is compilation as follows` [DCC Warning] VCLFixPack.pas(1625): W1000 Symbol 'ThemeServices' is deprecated: 'Use StyleServices' `

Comment: What if the solution lies in dealing with those warnings? Are you just going to give up? Not saying vclfixpack is your solution, but you reject it readily.

Comment: Yeah! I have rejected `VCL Fix Pack`, but what may be my solution?

Comment: Anyway, when I run your program it starts up beautifully. You seem quick to reject things. And ask for solutions, and example code. First of all we need to work out what the problem is. I cannot reproduce so I don't think I'll be any use to help you. **Update:** OK, now I can reproduce. Although what I reproduce is not what we call flicker. It's something else.

Comment: One minor point. Position = poDesktopCenter doesn't really play well with multi monitor systems.

Comment: First thing to do is to remove all the double buffering, and the alpha blending. The alpha blending won't play well with sheet of glass. That resolves some of the aritfacts.

Comment: If you do those changes then the only problem I see is that at startup the background suddenly changes after the initial show animation.

Comment: OK, if we can just stop that show animation, we'll be good! Let's see if I can work out how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

OK, let's see if this does what you need:

1. Remove all double buffering settings from your .dfm file.
2. Remove all alpha blend settings from your .dfm file. You are using sheet of glass which trumps alpha blend, I think.
3. Disable window transitions for your main form with a call to `DwmSetWindowAttribute`.

Point 3 requires a little more elaboration. You'll need the window handle in order to do this. You have to wait until the VCL has created the window. So, add an overridden `CreateWnd` to your form class.

```
procedure CreateWnd; override;
```

And implement it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.CreateWnd;
var
  dwAttribute: DWORD;
begin
  inherited;
  dwAttribute := DWORD(True);
  DwmSetWindowAttribute(WindowHandle, DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED, 
    @dwAttribute, SizeOf(dwAttribute));
end;
```

You'll need to add `Winapi.Dwmapi` to your `uses` clause.

Now the window shows instantly when you start your application. Suppression of the startup transition means that we no longer see the window displaying the wrong background before finally coming to its senses.

Now if you are desperate to have alpha blending too then I think you may be in trouble. When I enable sheet of glass and alpha blend, I see bizarre artifacts when hovering over window caption bar buttons. I think that the hover effects do not account for your alpha blend.

Comment: I have tried your procedure under `Public declarations` as well as `Protected declaration`, but I am getting error at compilation as `External exception C06D007E` in my current project and `failed to delete tab at index 0` error in another project.

Comment: @user2612109 `failed to delete tab at index 0` Is this even a Delphi error message? It sounds like you have your own tab sheet or page control and you have some of your own code which is deleting these tabs. That's a completely different unrelated issue.

Comment: @user So what of this? Does my answer address the problem?

Comment: Hi @DavidHeffernan I am considering your answer here. Just a quick question: If I put the procedure to my form class, no need to call it somewhere right? If so, I already tried it and I can still see the transition of my form design time size to windows state = maximized. Otherwise, does my case still relevant to this question?

Comment: Correct. The framework calls CreateWnd which is a virtual method.